# asp.net mvc login with email confirmation sendgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset#addRes

when i run it and it should send me a email confirmation it gives me a bad request.

```
    [Exception: Bad Request]
   SendGrid.<CheckForErrorsAsync>d__b.MoveNext() +165
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   SendGrid.<DeliverAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +741
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   WebApplication3.<configSendGridasync>d__3.MoveNext() in c:\Users\kasper\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs:47
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   WebApplication3.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\kasper\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs:24
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter.GetResult() +63
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<SendEmailAsync>d__129.MoveNext() +963
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   WebApplication3.Controllers.<Register>d__13.MoveNext() in c:\Users\kasper\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Controllers\AccountController.cs:166
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

i'm new to this platform and completely clueless, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  Examine the MVC example under:

```
private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
```

the credentials to log into SendGrid are defined using:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]);
```

So I checked with [SendGrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/csharp.html) for C# and they just simply ask for two strings.

I just passed two strings like so:

```
var username = "your_sendgrid_username";
var pswd = "your_sendgrid_password";
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
```

I hope that helps some people with implementation using SendGrid.  Must watch out for changes to SendGrid, using NuGet helps with that:

```
PM> Install-Package SendGrid
```

Aslo note that you must refrence some namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
```